# Kentico GET Form Data

Tags: content-management-system, kentico

I am currently trying to use the Kentico API to gather the data from all forms within Kentico.

So far I've found that there are two places to view form data and they can be found at these endpoints:

`/rest/cms.forms` <---- Returns all form definitions (excluding field data types

`/rest/bizformitem.bizform.FORM_NAME/` <---- Returns all form data (inserted by end users)

What I am trying to do is keep a record of all of the form data on a daily basis.  Is there a better way to do this using the API rather than making 'x' number of calls (one per form).

EDIE: Out of 100+ forms I only need to pull 15-20 of them on a daily basis.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all in sql  and it depends how many forms you have. Each form is separate sql table that has a record in CMS_Class table

-- this will give the list of all tables that you need query

```
select ClassTableName  from CMS_Class where ClassIsForm = 1
```

Then you can find out the ones that were updated let say with in the 24 hrs

```
SELECT 
      [db_name] = d.name
    , [table_name] = SCHEMA_NAME(o.[schema_id]) + '.' + o.name
    , s.last_user_update
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats s
JOIN sys.databases d ON s.database_id = d.database_id
JOIN sys.objects o ON s.[object_id] = o.[object_id]
WHERE o.[type] = 'U'
    AND s.last_user_update IS NOT NULL
    AND s.last_user_update BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
    and s.[object_id] in (select OBJECT_ID(ClassTableName)
    from CMS_Class where ClassIsForm =1 )
```

You might have a few hundred forms... to go and query few hundred tables might be unproductive. I usually get 18-20 out 100+ we have.

Comment: Where is the CMS_Class table located? - Also what sort of DB are you connected to?  I wasn't aware that I was able to (or already) had all this information stored in a Kentico DB, so that's why I am trying to use the REST API.

Comment: Kentio is MS SQL,  Almost anything in Kentico has a DB representation :). Whatever starts with CMS_ - internal Kentico tables, COM_ tables related to e-commerce modules, etc 


Check CMSConnectionString  in web.config of Kentico web site.  It will tell what database and what server

Comment: Interesting I use MS SQL! - As I am just a developer (first time using Kentico) how would I find the DB login for our system?  I didn't know that was even possible - since I'm just grabbing forms I could do most of this in SQL likely.

Comment: Check CMSConnectionString  in web.config of Kentico web site.  It will tell you what database and what server

:)
Good luck

Comment: Even if the instance I am working off of isn't self hosted?  How could I do this otherwise?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: While This is a great solution if it is self hosted - I do not have access to the database, and only have access to the API to get data with.

Answer (score 0):

There is Kentico API (not a REST API) that allows you to get all data you need at code behind. You can find examples [here](https://docs.kentico.com/api9/content-management/form-data).

Comment: Those examples are using the Kentico assemblies (which I don't have) I only have access to their API - any suggestions on how to just use their API?

Comment: Also it appears that it is a REST API : See here - https://docs.kentico.com/k9/integrating-3rd-party-systems/kentico-rest-service